# How do I get a "clean" string from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I run this code in python 3.6 (pythonanywhere.com) using MySQL

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect('username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com', 'username', 'password', 'username$to_do')

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT task FROM list')
rows = c.fetchall()
list_em = []
number = 0

for eatchRow in rows:
    list_em.append(eatchRow)
    print("nr %s: %s" % (number, list_em[number]))
    number += 1
del1 = int(input("Chose the number of the list item you want to delete: "))
delstatmt = "DELETE FROM list WHERE task = ?"
print (list_em[del1])
#c.execute(delstatmt, (list_em[del1],))
```

I am creating a list called "list_em" and fill with the content from the column "task" in the table "list". I would like "print (list_em[del1])" to return 'Gå med hunden' -A clean string that I can use to run the last script that is commented out. Instead get something that looks like this with brackets and a comma(from console):

```
nr 0: ('Skura Trappan',)
nr 1: ('Gå med hunden.',)
Chose the number of the list item you want to delete: 1
('Gå med hunden.',)
```

OBS! The table does not have any ID, just two columns:

```
mysql> select * from list;
+-----------------+-------------+
| task            | status      |
+-----------------+-------------+
| Skura Trappan   | Not started |
| Gå med hunden.  | Not started |
+-----------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're getting back from the MySQL library is a list of [tuples](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/python/tuples.html), one for each row returned by the query.  The elements of each tuple are the values of the columns you're querying for.

In this case, you're querying for one column, so each element of the list is a one-element tuple, which Python will represent as `(`*value*`,)` -- which is what you're seeing.

So in order to print out just the value from the tuple, you need to extract it, just like you would with a list:

```
for eatchRow in rows:
    list_em.append(eatchRow[0])
    print("nr %s: %s" % (number, list_em[number]))
    number += 1
```